# Documented symbol wifi.NULLMODE is nil?

Tags: nodemcu

I love the new tech ref at readthedocs.com, very nice... I just wish I could find firmware that matches them. :-)  I would like to call:

```
wifi.setmode(wifi.NULLMODE)
```

But it gives an error: "bad argument #1 to 'setmode' (number expected, got nil)"

`wifi.STATION` is 1, `wifi.SOFTAP` is 2, `wifi.STATIONAP` is 3, so I tried 0, -1 and 4, all gave an error: "wrong arg type".

I downloaded what appeared to be the latest firmware from git -- is there some other official source?

Any insight appreciated.

Comment: The best place to get the most recent version is to select the dev branch on nodemcu-build.com and pick the modules you need.

Comment: Is there any more feedback you need? If not I suggest you consider to accept the answer so that SO can mark this question as closed, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Comment: Adam B thanks, I did just that, now it wifi.NULLMODE is defined, but setting the mode to that doesn't seem to change behavior/current draw.  Also my interrupts don't work anymore, at first it whined about calls to gpio.trig that omitted the callback function (which used to be ok after the first call) but the function isn't firing?  Is there something special I have to do to get interrupt support when building?

Comment: @MarkMcGinty as I said wifi.NULLMODE will be fixed with #1018. As for your other issue(s) have a look at http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/gpio/#gpiotrig. If that doesn't help close here and ask a new question with full source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a pending PR that will fix this: https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/pull/1018/files#diff-708acae44868e2f538336aac253c2bc5R219

Comment: Was just merged today.